# cURL - PHP; Como fazer um looping no código?

Tags: php, libcurl

Preciso que no final do código ele apague os download que foi feito e baixe novamente, que fique se repetindo isso a cada 4 min. A cada 4 min ele executa esse script de "baixar, apagar e baixar novamente". 
Como fazer?! Agradeço de coração a quem ajudar, já foi muito trabalhoso esse código.

**O código ele:**

- Acessa o site
- Procura os arquivos .CSV e baixa tudo pra pasta downloads que fica junto ao script

```php
<?php

$x = new Nulogy();
$retorno = $x->iniciar();
echo $retorno;

class Nulogy{

public $u;
public $s;
public $url;
public $post;
public $resposta;
public $cookie;
public $token;
public $urlDownload;
public $dir;
public $nome;
public $ds;
public $arquivo;
public function __construct(){

  $this->u = 'login aqui';
  $this->s = 'senha aqui';
  $this->dir = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'download'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $this->cookie = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '/cookie/' .'NULOGY[COOKIE]' . rand(0, 999999) . '.txt';
}
public function iniciar(){
  $this->url = 'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in';
  $this->loginPlayLoad();
  $this->post();
  $validarLogin = $this->validarLogin();
  if($validarLogin === 'logado'){
  return $this->linkDownload();
  }else{
    return $validarLogin;
  }
}
public function loginPlayLoad(){
  $this->getTokenLogin();
  if($this->token){
    $data['utf8'] = '✓';
    $data['authenticity_token'] = $this->token;
    $data['return'] = '';
    $data['uv_login'] = '';
    $data['user[login]'] = $this->u;
    $data['user[password']= $this->s;
    $data['commit'] = 'Sign in';
    $data['authenticity_token'] = $this->token;
    $data['authenticity_token'] =$this->token;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
  $this->post = http_build_query($data);
  return true;
}
public function getTokenLogin(){
  $this->url = 'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in';
  $this->get();
  preg_match_all('/meta content="(.*?)" name="csrf-token"/', $this->resposta, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
  $token = $matches[0][1];
  if($token){
    return $this->token = $token;
  }else{
    return array('status' => false,'resposta' => 'Não foi possível encontrar CSRF-TOKEN' );
  }
  return false;
}
public function validarLogin(){
  if(preg_match_all('/title>(.*?)<.title>/', $this->resposta, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)){
    $titlo = $matches[0][1];
  }else{
  $titlo = false;
  }

  if((isset($titlo) && ($titlo === 'Sign in to PackManager') )) {
    return $titlo . ' Login ou senha inválidos.';
  }else{
    return 'logado';
  }
}
public function linkDownload(){
  $url = [
  'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/canned_reports/job_productivity?utf8=%E2%9C%93&generate_flag=true&filter_choice=project_customer&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Boperator%5D=between&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Bfrom_threshold%5D=2017-Jul-2+9%3A00+PM&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Bto_threshold%5D=2017-Jul-3+11%3A46+PM&columns%5B0%5D=project_code&columns%5B1%5D=item_code&columns%5B2%5D=actual_job_start_at&columns%5B3%5D=actual_job_end_at&columns%5B4%5D=line_name&columns%5B5%5D=performance&columns%5B6%5D=availability&columns%5B7%5D=line_efficiency&columns%5B8%5D=units_produced&columns%5B9%5D=units_expected&columns%5B10%5D=unit_of_measure&columns%5B11%5D=standard_units_per_hour&columns%5B12%5D=duration&order_by=actual_job_start_at&order_direction=desc&authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&format=csv',
  'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/jobs.csv?authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&customer_name=&from_scheduled_start_at=2017-Jul-2+00%3A00&has_production=all&item_code=&line_leader=all&line_leader_id=all&line_name=&page=1&project_code=&reconciliation_status=all&signed_off=no&status=all&to_scheduled_end_at=2017-Jul-3+23%3A59&utf8=%E2%9C%93',
  'https://packmanager.nulogy.net/canned_reports/job_downtime?utf8=%E2%9C%93&generate_flag=true&filter_choice=item_class_name&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Boperator%5D=between&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Bfrom_threshold%5D=2017-Jul-2+9%3A00+PM&query%5B0%5D%5Bactual_job_start_at%5D%5Bto_threshold%5D=2017-Jul-3+11%3A55+PM&columns%5B0%5D=job_id&columns%5B1%5D=line_name&columns%5B2%5D=downtime_reason_code&columns%5B3%5D=downtime_reason_name&columns%5B4%5D=downtime_duration&columns%5B5%5D=downtime_notes&order_by=actual_job_start_at&order_direction=desc&authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&authenticity_token='.urlencode($this->token).'&format=csv'];
  $nome = [0 => 'produtividade do trabalho.csv',1 => 'Trabalhos.csv' , 2 => 'inatividade do trabalho.csv'];
  $i = 0;

  foreach($url as $u):
    $this->urlDownload = $u;
    $this->nome = $nome[$i++];
    echo $this->dw();
  endforeach;
}
public function header(){
  $header = [
      "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
      "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
      "Connection: keep-alive",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1",
      "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ];
  return $header;
}
public function dw(){
    $this->url = $this->urlDownload;
    $this->get();
    $dw = $this->resposta;
    $this->arquivo = $this->dir.$this->nome;
    if($this->arquivosExiste()){

    file_put_contents($this->arquivo , $dw);
    $ret =  'Arquivo salvo na pasta: ' . $this->dir . '<br>';
    }else{
      $ret = 'Algum problema foi encontrado :/';
    }
    return $ret;
}
public function arquivosExiste(){
  if (is_file($this->arquivo)){
      unlink($this->arquivo);
   }
  return true;
}
public function post(){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header());
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
  $this->resposta = curl_exec($ch);
}
public function get(){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://packmanager.nulogy.net/sign_in");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->header());
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
  $this->resposta = curl_exec($ch);
}
}
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria implementar como se fosse para executar apenas uma vez o script, mas chamá-lo via tarefa agendada a cada 4 minutos. Arquivos que serão sobreescritos nem precisam ser deletados. E os arquivos que foram criados antes do início do script (observar a hora) podem ser deletados no final dele.

Comment: Configure sua cronJob para que execute o mesmo a cada 4 minutos, se cada arquivo for para um usuário específico, ele tera de executar a cronJob buscando todos os usuários, ou tera de ter um arquivo específico para cada usuário

Comment: Acredito que a melhor forma seja configurando um cronjob na tua hospedagem. Se for cPanel é mais fácil ainda, você só irá colocar o tempo de 4 minutos e irá colocar o caminho do arquivo php que apaga os arquivos do servidor e baixa novamente. Fica bem fácil fazer dessa forma. Abraço!

Comment: Bom, a melhor opção ao meu ver é você incrementar esse script para que ele faça todo o processo do início ao fim, ou seja, ele cria e deleta tudo, ao final dele, tem que ficar como se não tivesse feito. Sendo assim, você cria uma tarefa agendada, CRON JOB, e coloca uma repetição de 4 em 4 minutos, o que fará exatamente o que você quer.

Comment: Uma outra opção é executar em um loop no bash (eu utilizo quando o laço de repetição precisa ser menor que 1 minuto): $ while true; php script.php; sleep 180; done;

Comment: Existe algumas opções como cron job do próprio servidor linux, ou pode usar filas como SQS ou Redis, mas caso queira algo bem simples, dê uma olhada no ReactPHP, que serve justamente para você fazer loopings de ações: https://reactphp.org/

Comment: As vezes nem precisa usar o cronjob do linux: https://cron-job.org/de/

Answer (score -3):

Se estiver rodando em ambiente linux, pode simplesmente criar uma entrada na crontab para executar seu script com a periodicidade desejada.

Segue um site pasa se te guiar na configuração do cron:
https://crontab.guru/